# Using ESC event to cancel Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am looking for a way to allow a user to cancel a mouse drag operation by pressing the ESC key.

Can this be done using Javascript?

Thank you

**Update**

When the mouse is dragging a div element over a droppable area, pressing the ESC key should drag the element to an area that is not droppable.  Once the element is dragged to a non-droppable area, I invoke a "mouseup" event on the dragged element, which causes the dragged element to be dropped onto a non-droppable area.

How can I do this using jQuery Draggable and jQuery Droppable?

Comment: [Native drag and drop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dndevents) or [jQuery's draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag)? The native drag event is cancelable, jQuery's `drag` event may be by returning `false` (the docs do not specifically say so but returning `false` usually cancels an event; try it).

Comment: Okay, according to [this post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-cancel-drag-while-dragging#fullResponseContainer_14737000000849011) returning `false` should cancel the drag event.

Comment: I would like to use jQuery's draggable.

Comment: Try this see if this helps your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012655/jquery-ui-cancel-dragging-on-escape-key

Answer (score 8):

> When the mouse is dragging a div element over a droppable area, pressing the ESC key should drag the element to an area that is not droppable

I´ve created a [`demo`](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/JSTWFTFoiz6yLWAQl2vH/) of a possible solution that you can check in plunker.

As stated by [`@ioneyed`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1272576/ioneyed), you can select the dragged element directly using the selector `.ui-draggable-dragging`, which should be more efficient if you have lots of draggable elements.

The code used is the following, however, apparently it's not working in the snippet section. Use the `fullscreen` feature on the plunker or reproduce it locally.

```js
var CANCELLED_CLASS = 'cancelled';

$(function() {

  $(".draggable").draggable({

    revert: function() {

      // if element has the flag, remove the flag and revert the drop
      if (this.hasClass(CANCELLED_CLASS)) {
        this.removeClass(CANCELLED_CLASS);
        return true;
      }

      return false;

    }

  });

  $("#droppable").droppable();

});

function cancelDrag(e) {

  if (e.keyCode != 27) return; // ESC = 27

  $('.draggable') // get all draggable elements
    .filter('.ui-draggable-dragging') // filter to remove the ones not being dragged
    .addClass(CANCELLED_CLASS) // flag the element for a revert
    .trigger('mouseup'); // trigger the mouseup to emulate the drop & force the revert

}

$(document).on('keyup', cancelDrag);
```

```css
        .draggable {
          padding: 10px;
          margin: 10px;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        #droppable {
          padding: 25px;
          margin: 10px;
          display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>droppable</p>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>draggable</p>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>draggable</p>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>draggable</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css">
```

Comment: Why do you filter on `.ui-draggable-dragging` instead of making it your initial selector or doing a sub-select `$('.ui-draggable-dragging','.draggable')` ?

Comment: Your code does not work. Let's say that I am dragging the draggable element over the droppable element. When I press the ESE key, the draggable element should not be dropped on the droppable element. However, the solution provided by you allows the draggable element to be dropped onto the droppable element after the ESC key is pressed.

Comment: His solution is what you asked for however you didn't state you wanted the cancel to be persisted. Also, that is an easy append to the draggable to make it look for the cancelled class and ignore draggable state. `cancel: ".cancelled"` in your draggable declaration

Comment: I asked the element to be dropped on a non-droppable element when the ESC key is pressed.

Comment: what non-droppable element? since you haven't provided the HTML i´ve simple reverted the dragging, but it's easily done from there.

Comment: Basically, the UI has elements that are droppable and elements that are not droppable. Dropping a draggable element on a droppable element triggers some action. My currently implementation is the following. When the ESC key is pressed while I'm dragging an element over a droppable element, I set a variable called "dropAllowed" to be false. Then I invoke a "mouseup" event on the dragged element, which causes the dragged element to be dropped onto a droppable element. The dropppable element then calls the "drop" method of jQuery's Droppable. The drop returns false if "dropAllowed" is false.

Comment: However, my current implementation requires changes to be made to the drop handler of all droppable elements. This requires code changes in many files, which is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to help but without the expected result...
Searching on google you can find that **while dragging** other events are locked, similar behaviour to what happens during a *window.alert*...

By the way, I am on a Mac and I can capture all keyboard events but not "controls key such as command, ctrl, esc, ecc."

Hope help you as a starter point!

```js
function DragAndDropCtrl($) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.ESC = 27;
  self.draggables = $('.draggable');
  self.dropArea = $('#droppable');
  self.currentDraggingElement = null;
  self.currentDismissed = false;

  self.dismissDragging = function(event, eventManager) {
    
    self.currentDismissed = true;
    
    //Using the manager you can't use the revert function OMG!
    //return eventManager.cancel();
  };
  
  self.dropArea.droppable();
  self.draggables.draggable({
    revert: function() {
      var revert = self.currentDismissed;
      
      self.currentDismissed = false;
      console.log(revert, self.currentDismissed)
      
      return revert;
    },
    start: function() {
      self.currentDraggingElement = $(this);
    },
    end: function() {
      self.currentDraggingElement = null;
    }
    
  });
  
  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    
    console.log('key pressed', event)
    
    //How to intercept the esc keypress?
    self.dismissDragging(event, $.ui.ddmanager.current);
    
    if(event.which  === self.ESC || event.keyCode  === self.ESC) {
      self.dismissDragging(event, $.ui.ddmanager.current);
    }
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(DragAndDropCtrl);
```

```css
#droppable {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: lightseagreen;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin: 1em .3em;
}

.draggable {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: .5em 0;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: move;
}

.sidebar { width: 30%; float: left; }
.main { width: 70%; float: right; }
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
    <p>draggable</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
    <p>draggable</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
    <p>draggable</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="main">  
  <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>droppable</p>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css">
```